# Extracting a value based on the minimum of another variable (based on a group of another variable)

Tags: r

I am aware my title may not make sense so let me explain. I have a data frame full of about 3000 observations and multiple columns. An example is given as follows.

```
ID   T1        T2   
1  00:00:04  00:09:00
1  00:05:00  01:00:59
2  00:39:00  05:23:00
2  00:23:52  06:12:31
2  00:40:50  00:00:01
3  01:05:01  00:32:00
```

There are a few steps I want to do but if there is a code that does it all in one go that would be great. First of all I want to group by ID and find the minimum time for T2. I want this to be entered in a new column next to T2.This part is fine and the code I have used is as follows:

```
EarliestT2Time<-ddply(DataFirst, "ID", summarize, min=min(T2))
DataFirst$EarliestT2Time<-EarliestT2Time[,2]
```

This should look as follows:

```
ID   T1        T2     EarliestT2Time
1  00:00:04  00:09:00  00:09:00    
1  00:05:00  01:00:59  00:09:00
2  00:39:00  05:23:00  00:00:01
2  00:23:52  06:12:31  00:00:01
2  00:40:50  00:00:01  00:00:01
3  01:05:01  00:32:00  00:32:00
```

I next want to group by ID and only include one row for each ID where T1 is in the corresponding T2 minimum. Hence the data frame looks as follows.

```
ID   T1        T2     EarliestT2Time
1  00:00:04  00:09:00  00:09:00    
2  00:40:50  00:00:01  00:00:01
3  01:05:01  00:32:00  00:32:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An option is to convert it to `times` from `chron`, get the index of the minimum value and subset

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(EarliestT2Time = T2[which.min(times(T2))])
   #or use as.POSIXct from base R
   #mutate(EarliestT2Time = T2[which.min(as.POSIXct(T2, format = "%H:%M:%S"))])

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID       T1       T2 EarliestT2Time
#  <int>    <chr>    <chr>          <chr>
#1     1 00:00:04 00:09:00       00:09:00
#2     1 00:05:00 01:00:59       00:09:00
#3     2 00:39:00 05:23:00       00:00:01
#4     2 00:23:52 06:12:31       00:00:01
#5     2 00:40:50 00:00:01       00:00:01
#6     3 01:05:01 00:32:00       00:32:00
```

If we want to include only a single row, then do a `slice` or `filter`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(which.min(times(T2))) %>%
    mutate(EarliestT2Time = T2)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID       T1       T2 EarliestT2Time
#  <int>    <chr>    <chr>          <chr>
#1     1 00:00:04 00:09:00       00:09:00
#2     2 00:40:50 00:00:01       00:00:01
#3     3 01:05:01 00:32:00       00:32:00
```